# Matrix premultiplication

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

How can I obtain the generic matrix $T$ such that $\hat{X}=TX$ with:

$$\hat{X}=\begin{bmatrix} 
 a & 0 \\
 0 & b\\
 c & 0 \\
    0 & d \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$X=\begin{bmatrix} 
 a & b \\
 c & d
 \end{bmatrix}$$

I did several try without obtaining the result I needed.

Edit: The T matrix should be "independent" from the entries of the X matrix (i.e. a, b, c, d should not appear in T).

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show what you tried?  It's relatively straight-forward to just create an arbitrary $4\times2$ matrix, act with it on $X$, set the result equal to $\hat{X}$ element-wise, and then solve for the elements of the $4\times2$ matrix.  It's a little bit of algebra, but not bad, as long as $X$ is invertible.

Comment: My question was bad posed, the T matrix should be independent from the entries of the X matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such $T$ that's independent of the entries of $X$.

If there were such $T$, then consider the effect of swapping the columns of $X$,

$$X' = \begin{bmatrix}b&a\\d&c\end{bmatrix} = X\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

On one hand, $T$ was assumed to be generic and would transform $X'$ to the same format:

$$TX' = \begin{bmatrix}b&0\\0&a\\d&0\\0&c\end{bmatrix}$$

On the other hand, $TX'$ should be like $TX$ but with swapped columns:

$$TX' = TX\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&b\\c&0\\0&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}0&a\\b&0\\0&c\\d&0\end{bmatrix}$$

And note how the zero entries are at different positions.

Answer (score 2):

Is $X$ is invertible? Then just multilpy $X^{-1}$ at right of both side of equation.

Then T will be $\hat{X}X^{-1}$.

Comment: I edit my question since it was bad posed, sorry. The T matrix should be independent from the entries of the X matrix

Comment: @it8 Whether or not $T$ depends on $X$ can be easily obtained by calculating it directly.

Comment: Well, actually I tried it and in my findings I only found that T depends on X, that's the reason I asked here if there are different suggestions to proceed. Thank you for your help